# Couldn't understand managed version under Maven dependency hierarchy

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

In my pom.xml, I have a SikuliX Jar which has a transitive dependency on jna-platform. 
As seen in below image, version 4.5.2 has overrided version 5.4.0. 
But i dont understand, how this version is overrided as i have not specified any dependency for jna-platform. I had also verified that no any there dependency is fetching this jar. [image]

Please help me understand why this is happening. Any detailed document is well appreciated.

Related dependencies:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post all your pom.xml?

Comment: I can't, project is commercial and not allowed to post that. But I had posted all related dependencies.

Comment: Ok, then look at the related [pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sikulix/sikulixapi/2.0.4/sikulixapi-2.0.4.pom) and you'll see why there's that version management or look at the tab with effective POM, there you'll find these two versions

Comment: Still not convinced because 5.4.0 version for jna-platform is mentioned. How come 4.5.2 is overriding 5.4.0 version.

Comment: Try to clean your project and update maven, maybe you have just another version cached. As last test add <jna.version>5.4.0</jna.version>, as property, to force the version. Try also to look [here](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/882), it looks like a similar case.

Comment: Although I got the workaround, this property seems a much cleaner solution. Also, that link got me the reason that spring boot starter parent is forcing it down from 5.4.0 to 4.5.2. Thanks @WoAiNii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were using spring boot, as suggested here (there's also the reason of this behaviour):

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/SspiUtil$ManagedSecBufferDesc #882](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/882)

you can change your order of dependencies, or specify the exact version, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or add this property:

`<jna.version>5.4.0</jna.version>`